# Move folders from one location to another from excel macro

Tags: vba, excel

I wanted one help in moving complete folders from one path to another, my requirement is:

I have list of paths (different paths) in column `A2` to `A51` as source location and in column `B2` to `B51` destination location, I want to move column `A1` folder to `B1` destination location.

in column `A` there is a list of different 100 paths given and in column "B" there is a destination path where the folders should be moved.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to create a vba macro that loops through column A. [How to loop through a range](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221353(v=office.11).aspx)

It should then get the value from the column next to it & use this to call the [Copy Folder method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264819.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You're looking to move folders, so here's some code that Moves the origin into the target.

```
Sub MoveModules()

  'Add a Reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime

  'Column A should have a path like C:\test\AAA
  'Column B should have a path like D:\test\AAA

  'The move would MOVE C:\test\AAA to D:\test\AAA

  Dim rng As Range
  Dim aData As Variant
  Dim FSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
  Dim iCounter As Long
  Dim sOrigin As String
  Dim sTarget As String

  'Get the intersection of columns A and B and the usedrange
  Set rng = Range("A:B " & Sheet1.UsedRange.Address)

  If Not rng Is Nothing Then

    aData = rng
    Set FSO = New FileSystemObject

    For iCounter = LBound(aData) To UBound(aData)
      sOrigin = aData(iCounter, 1)
      sTarget = aData(iCounter, 2)
      If FSO.FolderExists(sOrigin) Then
        If Not FSO.FolderExists(sOrigin) Then
          FSO.MoveFolder sOrigin, sTarget
        Else
          MsgBox "Target folder already exists at '" & sTarget & "'"
        End If
      Else
        MsgBox "Can't find Source folder '" & sOrigin & "'"
      End If
    Next iCounter
  End If
End Sub
```